# How set attribute in livewire datepicker?

Tags: laravel-livewire

In livewire 1.3 app looking at DatePicker example at https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/alpine-js
I can not see how to set custom parameter to and to use it when date is selected?
I need to put into hidden input formated date for saving in db.
I add 1 parameter in attributes:

```
<x-date-picker
    wire:model="start_date"
    id="start_date"
    autocomplete="off"
    attributes="{hidden_element:'hidden_start_date'}"
/>
```

and in resources/views/components/date-picker.blade.php :
and try to read in in date selection event:

```
<div>
    <input
        x-data
        x-ref="input"
        x-init="new Pikaday({
            field: $refs.input,
            format:'M/D/YYYY',
            onSelect: function() {
                console.log(this.el); // that shows html code of datepicker
                console.log('getAttribute:');
                console.log(this.el.getAttribute('hidden_element')); // shown null
                
                $( this.el.getAttribute('hidden_element') ).val( dateToMySqlFormat(this._d) );
                // code above does not work !
            }
        })"
        type="text"
        {{ $attributes }}
    >
</div>
```

Which is the valid way ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found decision with :

```
<x-date-picker
    wire:model="start_date"
    id="start_date"
    autocomplete="off"
    hidden_element="hidden_start_date"
/>
```

and in my component :

```
<div>
    <input
        x-data
        x-ref="input"
        x-init="new Pikaday({
            field: $refs.input,
            format:'M/D/YYYY',
            onSelect: function() {
{{--                console.log(this);--}}
                $('#'+$el.getAttribute('hidden_element')).val( dateToMySqlFormat(this._d) );
            }
        })"
        type="text"
        {{ $attributes }}
    >
</div>
```

!